# CodenameOne plan for the cloud storage API

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, codenameone, parse4cn1

Since CodenameOne doesn't support "the cloud storage API" any more and the parse.com is going to retire soon as well. Does CodenameOne has any plan to release a new Cloud Storage API or provide suggestions/guidelines to help developers to deal with the parse4cn1 library code, cloud code, database structure and data in parse.com?

Answer (score 1):

That is something you will have to figure out yourself as parse4cn1 was initially contributed by a community member and wasn't developed by Codenameone team.

You can use a simple webservices created in php, python or java, hosted along your content with any ISP.

You may also have a look at [amazon aws](https://aws.amazon.com/) which is promising, they provide a cloud solution but their SDKs is not yet integrated to Codenameone.

Comment: To add a more "official" answer to the second part: We don't have any short term plans to add a replacement for that as we are already stretched to capacity with our current goals. Adding an abstraction to AWS as a cn1lib on top of their REST API seems like something really doable.

Answer (score 0):

I made the `parse4cn1` lib and I'm also wondering what's smartest to do. With the announcement of Parse.com's imminent shutdown, there's been a lot of discussion around alternatives. My feeling is that "the dust is yet to settle" as per what options are best and reliable for the longer term (it would be a pity to migrate to another service only for it to be shut down soon). So I personally plan to wait till sometime in Q2 to do a proper evaluation of the alternatives. Hopefully, there'll be more clarity then.

The option to host one's own [Parse server](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/hosting-your-own-parse-on-aws-and-heroku/) (e.g. on AWS or Heroku) is getting interesting. They recently [announced](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-server-push-notifications/) support for push notifications on iOS and Android. If (when?) they open source the Parse.com dashboard code, I think that option would be much more interesting.

At some point in the coming months, I plan to make a parse4cn1 release that exposes an option to set the server path. With that, anyone migrating to the Parse server option should, in principle, be able to continue to use the cn1lib. Of course, for features that are supported by the open source Parse server.

PS: Here are pointers to some of such discussions on Parse alternatives:

- https://github.com/relatedcode/ParseAlternatives
- http://www.slant.co/topics/5219/compare/~firebase_vs_kumulos_vs_kinvey

Comment: Thank you sidiabale for your sharing.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, it seems there's some hope with open-sourcing the  Parse dashboard. See this github ticket: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3

Comment: Thank you for your sharing.

Comment: The first version of Parse dashboard is now available: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard I'm yet to try it out but I'm glad that things are going in this direction. It should now be viable to host your parse server somewhere and with the parse4cn1 change proposed above, things should just work ;)

Comment: I found this service which offers a hosted parse server: [https://parseapi.back4app.com/](https://parseapi.back4app.com/).  It should work 'as is' after migrating the app and changing the url in the library. How can we change the url in the meantime, before you release the new version?

Comment: Changing the `API_ENDPOINT` in `ParseConstants.java` should work. See the source code [here](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/blob/master/src/com/parse4cn1/ParseConstants.java#L27)

Comment: I set up mongodb, parse-server and parse-dashboard on my laptop. I can access the the dashboard via http://localhost:4040/apps/ and see my app. I can create classes for it. However, I can't access tables in my app using parse4cn1 library because I don't know the values for _applicationID_ and _clientKey_ to call the _Parse.initialize()_. My **parse-dashboard-config.json** file like this **{"apps":[{"serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/app","appId": "appID","masterKey": "masterKey",
"appName": "app"}]}**. I also don't know which is correct value to change for the _ParseConstants.API_ENDPOINT_

Comment: Please consult Parse server documentation for how to get the keys you need. I would expect your API_ENDPOINT to be your server URL.