# Will Parse4cn1 still work after Parse server retirement?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, codenameone, parse4cn1

I've been looking for a way to send push notifications to Android, iOS and Windows phone devices. I've come across the Parse4cn1 library. This library uses Parse. However i saw on the Parse site that they will retire soon. I have the following questions regarding the Parse4cn1 library and the retirement of Parse.

- Does the Parse4cn1 library still work after Parse's retirement?
- Do i need to setup my own open source Parse server to support the push notifications and when i do this does it also support push notifications for Windows Phone? (http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-server-push-notifications/ says it doesn't but i'm not entirely sure.)

Kind regards,

R Visser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636294/codenameone-plan-for-the-cloud-storage-api) related SO question.

In any case, `parse4cn1` will not support features that are not available in Parse Server. As far as I know, push is currently only supported for Android and iOS by Parse Server. So when `parse4cn1` is updated, it will support those. However, I've not scheduled that update yet. Feel free to chip in if you have the time/resources to update the library and issue a pull request. I'll be glad to review and merge it.

By the way, I recently came across [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) which claims to offer free push notification on a wide range of platforms. I have my reservations though as they apparently sell your data and unspecified device info to third parties in return for the free push services. I'm yet to do a full evaluation so don't take my word for it. Have a look yourself and decide if it's interesting to you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately i don't have the time to help you update the library.

Comment: No problem. It will happen at some point. Anyone who needs it faster will need to get his/her hands dirty ;)

Comment: I've released an [update](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/releases/tag/parse4cn1-3.0) of parse4cn1 that enables usage of Parse Server. However, this version does not include push notification support. If that's very important to you, please fill the short suvey on [this page](https://www.smash-ict.com/blog/parse4cn1-is-now-parse-server-ready/).